# XSL file causing error when stylesheet is included

Tags: css, xml, xslt, google-chrome

I have a XML file with code like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <?xml-stylesheet href="rss2.xsl" type="text/xsl" media="screen"?> <rss version="2.0">   <channel>
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <description>Description</description>
        <link>
        some link
        </link>
        <copyright>Copyrights 2012, All Rights Reserved</copyright>
        <item>
        <title> title 1</title>
        <description> desc</description>
        <link>
        some link
        </link>
        </item>   </channel> </rss>
```

And an XSL file for this is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>XML RSS Feed</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="rss_xsl.css" >
  </head>
  <body>
  <h2>XML RSS Feed</h2>
  <hr />

    <div id="content">
      <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
      <div class="article">
        <h3><a href="{link}" rel="bookmark"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></a></h3>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="description"/></p>
      </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The issue is when i comment the stylesheet code then chrome shows the feed. when i include the style the feeds are no more visible. How can this stop showing the feeds. is their some thing wrong with this inclusion of Style for XSL files..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the stylesheet markup is not well-formed, due to `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="rss_xsl.css" >` which should be `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="rss_xsl.css"/>`. Then I think the approach works when loading over HTTP. If you load the XML document from the file system then I think Chrome refuses to load the the stylesheet linked to, for security reasons. There might be command line options or settings to change the behavior.

Comment: One other issue that i want this file to work for all different types of feeds that i have like for news, sports, updates, entertainment. How can i dynamically Change the Heading for XSL file, like the title etc....

Comment: You should really ask a new question for that but of course doing something like `<title><xsl:value-of select="/rss/channel/title"/></title>` should be easy.